# Keyboard/typing tutor for Hebrew>

Tags: resource-request, keyboard-layout

The only typing tutors I can find mentioned [here](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/3240/10160) are for Linux.

Is there something out there that I can use on Windows?

Comment: Since the other question is not about Linux, your question is strictly a duplicate of the other one.